# Regex. Replace particular characters in string

Tags: regex, pcre

In the following string i need to replace (with Regex only) all _ with the dots, except ones that are surrounded by digits. So this:

> _this_is_a_2_2_replacement_

Should become

> .this.is.a.2_2.replacement.

Tried lots of things. That's where i got so far:

```
([a-z]*(_)[a-z]*(_))*(?=\d_\d)...(_)\w*(_)
```

But it obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try finding the following regex pattern:

```
(?<=\D)_|_(?=\D)
```

And then just replace that with dot.  The logic here is that a replacement happens whenever an underscore which has at least one non digit on either side gets replaced with a dot.  The regex pattern I used here asserts precisely this:

```
(?<=\D)_    an underscore preceded by a non digit
|           OR
_(?=\D)     an underscore followed by a non digit
```

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PCRE, you could assert a digit on the left of the underscore and match a digit after. Then use make use of [SKIP FAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex).

In the replacement use a dot:

```
(?<=\d)_\d(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|_
```

- `(?<=\d)` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is a digit
- `\d(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` Consume the digit which should not be part of the match result
- `|` Or
- `_` Match a single underscore

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/24eIfI/1)

Comment: Every day i learn something new, this is new thing i learnt today :)